# Flagging for comments, questions and answers, can we flag users?

Tags: discussion

In one of the SE sites I frequent, we've now had two racially oriented questions asked. The user is very smart about how he words them, yet his phrasing indicates he (may be) racist.

If I find a comment, question, or answer offensive, or hate speech, I can flag them. How would we 'flag' a user?

Answer (score 1):

On the SE sites I've been on the procedure is to flag a post of the user with a custom flag and explain clearly what the problem is, and the moderators can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

An effective means is to flag the user's contributions (answers, comments etc), using the 'Other' options for posts or comments when flagged - objectively state what the issue is clearly based on what the user has posted.  If it has happened before, include this information in your comment to the moderators.